# How to have more audio outputs for the one audio input?

Tags: audio

Current setup is like this.
[image: Current setup]

One more output is needed for active speakers next to the PC. What is needed to split the signal going to the amplifier also to go to the PC speakers? Something simple I can buy? What is such device called? Is there something like the opposite of a mixer which instead of multiple inputs going to one output takes a single input and puts it to multiple outputs? Or should I just cut the cables and solder them to a three pole switch?

[image: Expected new setup]

Comment: A splitter might be all you need. Perhaps try searching for "audio splitter."

Comment: Some professional audio terminology for this: "broadcast splitter", "mult box", or "press box." Also maybe "distribution amplifier". You might also look at "headphone amplifiers" as they often have multiple outputs as well.

Comment: Why not use a simple cable - but you don't even mention which connectors.

Comment: Maybe add a separate DAC to the PC for the speakers. That way, you get to choose the O/P at the PC stage, rather than add another ??? box. E.g., I've got a FiiO headphone DAC thing that Windows 10 switches to when I switch it on, and reverts to the previous audio output when I switch it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use a passive splitter (Y-cable).  I would suggest putting this in the TV output; the headphones are likely 32-ohm impedance and draw energy from the audio output while the TV may well present a higher impedance and draw very little power, so be adding an extra load should result in minimal reduction in output.

Comment: I got 2 Y-splitter adapters and put those behind the QDAC. Works great.